# Why must a projection matrix be a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, projection

The below link and many other sources say that a projection matrix is a square matrix.

[Does a projection matrix have to be a square matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521372/does-a-projection-matrix-have-to-be-a-square-matrix)

Here is my understanding of linear transformation. Let a vector space $V$ and $W$ have a set of basis $\{v_1, ... , v_n\}$ and $\{w_1, ... , w_m\}$, respectively. A linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow W$ can be represented by a matrix $P$ for a given set of basis for $V$ and $W$. For $v \in V$ where $v = x_1v_1 + ... +x_nv_n$ and $w = y_1w_1 + ...+y_mw_m$, let $x = (x_1 ... x_n)$ and $y = (y_1...y_m)$. Then, what holds is $\mathbf{y}^\top = P\mathbf{x}^\top$, not $w = Pv$. So, my understanding of $P$ is that it does not transform a vector in $V$ to another vector in $W$, but it transforms the coordinates under given bases of $V$ and $W$.

If my understanding is correct, since projection is a linear transformation from a vector space to its subspace, let's say $m$ is smaller than $n$. Then, when we project a vector $v$ in $V$ onto a subspace $W$, the projected vector $P(v)$ should be represented by $m$ coordinates that are coefficients of the $m$ basis vectors of the subspace $W$. Since what $P$ does is the transformation of coordinates, shouldn't $P$ be an $m$ by $n$ matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So projection maps can be defined for abstract vector spaces without the need for fixing a basis.
In particular, fix a vector space $V$ and subspace $W$.
The features that we would like a projection to have are that

1. $P$ maps everying onto $W$, ie. $P(v) \in W$ for any $v \in V$.
2. $P$ leaves elements already in $W$ unchanged, ie $P(w) = w$ for any $w \in W$.

The first condition is totally compatible with thinking of $P$ as a map $V\rightarrow W$.
However, in order to make sense of the statement $P(w) = w$, it is necessary that $P(w)$ and $w$ live in the same space.

That is, for our abstract notion of projection to align with our intuition, we require the codomain and domain of $P$ to be the same.
Hence, we must define $P\colon V \rightarrow V$, which is why the matrix representation of $P$ is necessarily square.

Moreover, once we have established that both the domain and codomain of $P$ should be $V$, this allows us to make a very terse and useful definition for a projection map.
That is, any linear transformation $P\colon V\rightarrow V$ that satisfies $P^2 = P$ (check that this is equivalent to the two conditions outlined previously).

---

Now, given a projection $P\colon V \rightarrow V$ onto $W$, it certainly makes sense and is often useful to consider the map $P' \colon V \rightarrow W$ defined by $P'(v) = P(v)$, but this map is not called a projection as is doesn't make sense to write $(P')^2$ anymore.

Also, once we consider $W$ as a separate vector spacein its own right, it makes sense to do thinks like fix different bases for $V$ and $W$, in which case any full-rank matrix with the right dimensions can represent such a map.